# How to organize php project directory stucture and Clean URLs

Tags: php, model-view-controller, directory, project

I'm new in PHP. I have completed my intermediate training. Now start working in new projects. I generate my directory structure like this

```
/include
inside include i have class files & function files 

/public
inside main public folder i have index.php another public pages. like listing, post etc..

/public/admin
inside admin i have admin pages like create, delete and data list 

/public/stylesheet
/public/js
/public/images

/public/layout
/public/layout/header.php
/public/layout/footer.php

/log
```

Now this is my simple project directory structure. I gets very confuse when i saw some people project they have only one index page in main and call all pages from it and clean its url. Now my question is that anyone can suggestion best way from where i can learn about this project structure organization and clean URLs according to nowadays standard. I searched about it google but i couldn't find best resource.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a [front controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/create_framework/front_controller.html) in what you are seeing used. For a project structure you should seek inspiration from some established framework (Symfony, Laravel, etc.). And maybe you should actually use one. Even if your project is small, you'd still benefit from some (lightweight minimalist) framework.

Comment: yes i read about framework. I also wanted to use Laravel but i think this is not right time to use before i have to cover my self my own when i will think my concept is clear i need to move on next step so then framework for me is best. So that's why i start working to create my own CMS then move on to next with framework

Comment: many of people recommend me to use smarty engine templating. I also going to used it. I just want better resource to organize my project according to nowadays standards Like MVC